# How do I get Isset() to ignore an empty field?

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, isset

Not sure if I'm taking the right approach here. I want something to display only if a value is set in the field.  I've tested this several ways.
1) If the value is set, then it displays correctly.
2) If I make up some random variable, then "N/A" is correctly displayed. But,
3) If the value in the field has NO set value, the echoed text still appears and of course without any set value.

```
if (isset($row['DATE'])) {
    echo "Dated: {$row['DATE']} <br />" ;
} else {echo "N/A" ; }
```

So what am I missing? How do I get this code to recognize and ignore an empty field?

Comment: I'm guessing since you've tagged this `sql` AND that you're using terminology such as 'field', you're pulling this data from a database, but you haven't indicated that in the body of your question.

Comment: List the table from mysql console. Do you see (NULL) for the empty DATE columns?? If so Try this ($row['DATE']  != "NULL")

Answer (score 1):

[`empty()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) will return true if the given variable is not set or evaluates to false:

```
if (!empty($row['DATE'])) {
    echo "Dated: {$row['DATE']} <br />" ;
} else {echo "N/A" ; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You looking for empty() function. They will return false if variable is empty or is not set.

Answer (score 0):

I would use another if checking if the value is not set `(!isset($row['DATE']))`
Rgds.

Comment: This approach did not recognize the values if they were set.  (!empty()) did the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: I shoud have expanded on the idea a bit more: the idea was to first check if not set the with else if check if set and then an else with the N/A `if (!isset($row['DATE'])){}else if (isset($row['DATE'])){yourcode}else {another code}.